# Create a set of rules if counting two or more variables. from html form

Tags: php, arrays, count

I want to create a set of rules in php
I have a form with 2 select fields ( with values from 1->5

```
Cookies are:
$Field1 = intval($_POST["Field1"]);
$Field2= intval($_POST["Field2"]);
```

ANd i want to create a rule as example below

```
Field1 has 1 selected and Field2 has 2 selected

if ( count($Field1) = 1) and ( count($Field2) = 2)
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
```

or

```
Field1 has 2 selected and Field2 has 3 selected

if ( count($Field1) = 2) and ( count($Field2) = 4)
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
```

or

```
Field1 has 2 selected and Field2 has 3 selected

if ( count($Field1) = 2) and ( count($Field2) = 3)
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"));
```

and so on.

Is this posible?

The above code is not correct but i have enter it to show what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the recent declaration from you:

> the result should be : One awwat with 3 cakes, and one arre with 2
>   cakes. One array can be filled with 3 cakes naxinun.

the following code will do what you expect:

```
<?php

class boxes
{
    private $_boxes = array();
    public $maxCake = 3; // default .. 3

    public function addBox()
    {
        $this->_boxes[] = array();
    }

    public function getBoxes()
    {
        return $this->_boxes;
    }

    public function addCake($boxNum = 0, $cake = array('paxType' => 'Cake'))
    {
        if (empty($this->_boxes)) {
            $this->addBox();
        }

        if (empty($this->_boxes[$boxNum])) {
            $this->_boxes[$boxNum] = array();
        }

        // if box is full with cakes (maxCake) create a new one
        if (count($this->_boxes[$boxNum]) == $this->maxCake) {
            $oldBoxNum = $boxNum;
            // searching for a box with enough space for another cake
            foreach ($this->_boxes as $key => $box) {
                if (count($box) != $this->maxCake) {
                    $boxNum = $key;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if we can't found one we add a new box
            if ($oldBoxNum == $boxNum) {
                $this->addBox();
                $boxNum++;
            }
        }

        $this->_boxes[$boxNum][] = $cake; 
    }
}

$Field1 = 1; // boxes
$Field2 = 5; // cakes

$boxes = new boxes();
$boxes->maxCake = 3; // if there are more than 3 cakes in a box, a new box will be created

// create number of boxes given with field1
for ($x = 0; $x < $Field1; $x++) {
    $boxes->addBox();
}

// add cakes given with field2
$y = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < $Field2; $x++) {
    $boxes->addCake($y);
    $y++;
    if ($Field1 == $y) {
        $y = 0;
    }
}

$result = $boxes->getBoxes();
for ($x = 0; $x < count($result); $x++) {
    echo 'Box' . ($x + 1) . ':';
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($result[$x]);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Box1:
Array (
    [0] => Array( [paxType] => Cake )
    [1] => Array( [paxType] => Cake )
    [2] => Array( [paxType] => Cake )   
)                                                      

Box2:  
Array (                                                      
    [0] => Array( [paxType] => Cake )
    [1] => Array( [paxType] => Cake )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

what result do you expect?
if you do something like this:

```
$box = array();
// Field1 has 2 selected and Field2 has 3 selected
if ($Field1 == 2) and ($Field2 == 4) {
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
}
print_r($box);
```

the only result will be a array with the item count you submit within $Field2.

```
//output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array([paxType] => Cake),
    [1] => Array([paxType] => Cake),
    [2] => Array([paxType] => Cake),
    [3] => Array([paxType] => Cake)
)
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan . My expected results are:Ex: If Field1 has 2 selected and Field 2 has 3 selected, I want to push two arrays. One array with 2 Cakes and one array with one cake within it.

Comment: @RazvanBaba - okay, and what result to you expect if field1 has 1 selected and field2 has 5 selected?

Comment: the result should be : One awwat with 3 cakes, and one arre with 2 cakes. One array can be filled with 3 cakes naxinun.